# Explain seq example seq(stats::rnorm(20))

Tags: r, seq

In the R manual there is one example of `seq` as follows:

```
seq(stats::rnorm(20))
```

Can someone explain to me what it is doing and is supposed to generate?

Answer (score 4):

You are effectively using this argument `along.with` in the `seq` function. This argument will tell seq to simply make a vector of the length of the object, which is 20 in your case.

From `?seq`:

> generates the sequence 1, 2, ..., length(from) (as if argument
>   along.with had been specified), unless the argument is numeric of
>   length 1 when it is interpreted as 1:from (even for seq(0) for
>   compatibility with S). Using either seq_along or seq_len is much
>   preferred

Comment: Stephen, thank u for your quick reply. I am a novice in R.

Answer (score 0):

The help also says

```
seq(stats::rnorm(20)) # effectively 'along'
```

So you are using the argument `along.with`, which reads:

> `along.with   take the length from the length of this argument.`

That's why it generates a sequence with 20 integers, as it's `length(rnorm(20L))`

Comment: RHertel, thank u for your quick reply. I am a novice in R.